# How to select previous elements until specified with JQ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I inherited template with the menu in which categories and subcategories is in the same scope. Here is an example:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="cat" data-item-type="category"></li>
    <li data-item-type="sub-category"></li>
    <li data-item-type="sub-category"></li>
    <li data-item-type="sub-category"></li>
    <li data-item-type="sub-category"></li>
    <li class="cat" data-item-type="category"></li>
    <li data-item-type="sub-category"></li>
    <li data-item-type="sub-category"></li>
    <li data-item-type="sub-category"></li>
    <li data-item-type="sub-category"></li>
    <li class="cat" data-item-type="category"></li>
    <li class="cat" data-item-type="category"></li>
    <li data-item-type="sub-category"></li>
    <li data-item-type="sub-category"></li>
</ul>
```

I cant change the structure of this, but can add extra attributes to it.

So my question is if it is possible to select all categories subcategories when clicking on one of **subcategories**. In general i need to select all `li` until first `class="cat"` or `data-item-type="category"` occurrence including it - category and all it's subs.

Comment: Take a look at the next-matching-sibling operator: http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update answer per OP's update:

```
$('li[data-item-type="sub-category"]').click(function() {
  $(this)
     .add( $(this).nextUntil('.cat') )
     .add( $(this).prevUntil('.cat') )
     .prev('.cat').addBack() //in jQuery < 1.8, replace addBack by andSelf
     //do something
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/usokar/7/edit)

After some brainstorming in the comments, here's a shorter alternative:

```
$('li[data-item-type="sub-category"]').click(function() {
  $(this).prevAll('.cat:first').nextUntil('.cat').addBack()//do something
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/usokar/11/edit)

So `.prevAll('.cat:first')` matches the first previous `.cat`, `nextUntil('.cat')` gets all its subcategories and `addBack` (or `andSelf` in older versions) adds the `.cat` element back to the set of matched elements.

In up-to-date jQuery versions, the `.add()` and `.addBack()` methods sort the matched elements in document order, hence both alternatives will have `.cat` as the first element in the set followed by the subcategories in document order.

---

### *Reference*

- [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)
- [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)
- [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
- [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)
- [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)
- [`prevUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/)

Comment: i need to get it when clicking on sub, not on cat.

Comment: almost there, but i also need the category there.

Comment: @Kirix You mean the category that comes before the first subcategory in the group right?

Comment: @Kirix Alright, with this update I believe now it is 100% according to your question's reqs. I'll try to refactor this code a bit while you review.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté note : this won't work with categories that don't have subcats

Comment: @CME64 Yes I'm aware of it. The OP states "when clicking on one of **subcategories**." so I believe the `.cat` itself shouldn't have this behavior.

Comment: did this in more simpler way `var category = element.prevAll('.cat');
 var all = jQuery(category[0]).nextUntil('.cat').get();
 all.unshift(category[0]);`

Comment: @Kirix I tried to keep my answer the most readable, but your code looks pretty efficient too. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I thought he wanted the click to be triggered even on the categories when he said "any of them",, he fixed the question now

Comment: @Kirix use '.cat:first' with prevAll or you will select all categories before it which you don't need,, and you can nest them in one line

Comment: @CME64 My interpretation of the last paragraph still stands. "when clicking on one of subcategories" means that the trigger should be the subcategory, and the elements matched should be "category and all it's subs". OP can make this clearer if my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: `element.prevAll('.cat:first').nextUntil('.cat').addBack()` should work as well (instead of converting to native array with `.get` and `unshift`)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté you are right and I said that in the previous comment, no hard feelings

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem according to your request  (updated) for category and subs (not buggy)

```
  $('li').click(function() {
       var x = $(this).add($(this).nextUntil('.cat')).add($(this).not('.cat').prevUntil('.cat')).andSelf().add($(this).not('.cat').prevAll('.cat:first'));
  });
```

for clicking on the **subs** or the **cat** and selecting the other subs around it with it's **category** too

Comment: +1 it works when clicking the `.cat` too in case OP needs that functionality. Here's a demo for your code http://jsbin.com/usokar/10/edit

Comment: thanks for making a demo of my code ,, although Kirix's is better as an idea if it were organized

Comment: You mean better indented/line breaks? Feel free to edit/style it and add to the answer if you feel like. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [`.nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
$('li.cat').on('click', function() {
   $(this).nextUntil('.cat');
   /* then write you logic here */
});
```